# Validating excel column name using c# and microsoft interop

Tags: c#, excel

I have only 1 row, and 18 columns to validate from an excel file. I need to check if the column name mentioned is the same as what I desired. For example, col A1= Name, colA2= Address and so on. I think I can use array but unsure how to connect between the cells and the colum name in my arraylist.

```
Range rng = xlApp.get_Range("A1", "R1");
            string[] colName = new string[] {"Name","Address",....};
           
            foreach (rng in colName )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Range rng = xlApp.get_Range("A1", "R1");
string[] colName = new string[] {"Name","Address",....};

Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
           
foreach (var (rng, index) in colName.WithIndex()){

// Validation
if(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, (index + 1)].toString() == rng)
{

// your code

}

}
```

Also see this- http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm

Comment: hi, thank you for answer. but the index seems to be error in my code.  how can i solved it